# SQL Filter in the where clause

Tags: sql, dynamic, filtering, where-clause

I'm not sure how to approach this issue 100% but I think it will likely be something using dynamic SQL. The user would like the ability to use a checkbox on the GUI to pass in variables. Not all checkboxes will be checked passing in data. Only a few will be checked at a time. I voted for radio box, anyway so the issue is now I have to filter based on the variables they pass in that are checked. So in the WHERE clause it needs to dynamically filter. I've used Dynamic SQL rarely and I'm not a DBA. So if I pass in two values with data and one is null, how do I prevent it from filtering in the Where clause when one of the values is nothing or null.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE
@obj1 AS NVARCHAR(10) = 'data',
@obj2 AS NVARCHAR(10) = 'data',
@obj3 AS NVARCHAR(10) = '',

SELECT something FROM Table WHERE 
IF @obj1 is not null then filter,
If @obj2 is not null then filter,
If @obj3 is not null then filter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OR`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE (@obj1 IS NULL OR ( ... filter with @obj1 here  ) ) AND
      (@obj2 IS NULL OR ( ... filter with @obj2 here  ) ) AND
      (@obj3 IS NULL OR ( ... filter with @obj3 here  ) )
```

If, for example @obj1 is `NULL` then the corresponding predicates concerning `@obj1` will be eliminated from the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Holmes Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.